# onClick function called at render time in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my render function,i am dynamcially dispalying a set of products with details such as their image,price,quantity increase/decrease and the amount which the user has already bought.Now i would like to attach a function on onCLick with parameters so that i can delete this product and hide it from the rendered HTML page.Here is what i have tried so far.

What happens is that when the page gets rendered,the onClick functions get automaticaly called which is something i don't want.

Here is the code for the same.

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import './view_cart.css'
import {ToastContainer, toast,style} from 'react-toastify'

class View_cart extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={item_list:{},"total_items_price":'',product_count:''}
    this.view_cart_details=this.view_cart_details.bind(this)
    this.delete_item_cart=this.delete_item_cart.bind(this)
  }

  registeration_notification(value_to_render)
  {
    toast(value_to_render,
      {
        //position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        autoClose: 3000,
      }
    );
  }

  product_state(e)
  {
    this.setState({"product_count":e.target.value})
    //console.log(this.state.product_count)
  }

  display_cart()
  {
    //console.log(Object.keys(this.state.item_list))
    const mapping = Object.keys(this.state.item_list).map((item,id) =>
    {
      console.log(this.state.item_list[item]['image_path'])
      var location = require('./Images/'.concat(this.state.item_list[item]['image_path']))
      //console.log(location)
      return (
        <div>
          <div class="container">
            <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style={{width:50}}>Product</th>
                  <th style={{width:10}}>Price</th>
                  <th style={{width:8}}>Quantity</th>
                  <th style={{width:22}} class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                  <th style={{width:10}}></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td data-th="Product">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src={location} alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h4 class="nomargin">{this.state.item_list[item]["Name"]} {'by '.concat(this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"])}</h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Price">{this.state.item_list[item]["original_price"]}</td>
                  <td data-th="Quantity">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="1"/>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">{this.state.item_list[item]['price']}</td>
                  <td class="actions" data-th="">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={this.delete_item_cart(this.state.item_list[item]["Name"],this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"])}><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
          )
    })
  return mapping
}

  sample_string()
  {
    console.log("ONCLICK WORKING")
  }
  sample_cookie_output()
  {
    const test_cookie_testing = new Cookies();

    var auth_string='Token '
    console.log((auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization'))),typeof((auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization')))))
    return (auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization')))
  }

  delete_item_cart(product_name_delete,manufacturer_name)
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_item_cart/',
    {
      method:"POST",
      headers:
      {
      'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
      body:JSON.stringify({"product_name":product_name_delete,"manufacturer":manufacturer_name})

  })
  .then(something =>something.json())
  .then(findResponse =>
    {
      console.log(findResponse,typeof(findResponse))
      if((Object.keys(findResponse).length)===1 && (Object.keys(findResponse).includes("Data Deletion")))
      {
        //console.log("A user with this name already exists.")
        this.registeration_notification("The Product has been removed from the cart")
      }
    }
  )
  }

  view_cart_details()
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_cart/',
    {
      method:"GET",
      headers:
      {
        'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
  })
.then(something =>something.json())
.then(findResponse =>
  {
    console.log(findResponse)
    this.setState({"item_list":findResponse[0],"total_items_price":findResponse[1]})
  }

)
  }

componentDidMount(){
  this.view_cart_details()
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <App/>
      {this.display_cart()}
      <button onClick={this.delete_item_cart}>Test Button</button>
      <ToastContainer/>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default View_cart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you call the `this.delete_item_cart` at render time.

So when you write

```
onClick={
  this.delete_item_cart(
    this.state.item_list[item]["Name"],
    this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"]
  )
}
```

the curly braces represent an *expression* which, here, is a function call which return value will be used as the `onClick` prop value.

What you want here is not the return value but an actual function to pas as a prop so what are the options here ?

For example, if you wrote

```
onClick={this.delete_item_cart}
```

It would "work" because you are passing a function as the expression, not its return value.

An obvious solution here is to wrap the function in another function like so:

```
onClick={() =>
  this.delete_item_cart(
    this.state.item_list[item]["Name"],
    this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"]
  )
}
```

### What have we done here?

We created an anonymous function which returns the function we want to call with its arguments. So when clicking, the `this.delete_item_cart` function will be called with specified arguments.

This arrow notation can be difficult to understand sometimes so this is what it would look like using ES5 functions :

```
onClick={function () {
  return this.delete_item_cart(
    this.state.item_list[item]["Name"],
    this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"]
  )
}}
```

I hope this helps you understand and unstuck you on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
onClick={this.delete_item_cart(this.state.item_list[item]["Name"],this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"])}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.delete_item_cart(this.state.item_list[item]["Name"],this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"])}
```

Documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: But the Delete_item_cart function accepts this parameters and calls an API to delete the item.So by using the syntax that you have mentioned,will the call still work?

Comment: In fact, with the first syntax, the method is called when the `render()` method is called. Here the arrow function wraps this so it is called on actual clicking.

Comment: With JSX you pass a function as the event handler
if you refer to a method with ()
onClick={() => do()}
without ()
onClick={do}